# Symbolic Programming and Packages in LISP

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Given the following function, entered at the REPL:

```
(defun animalp (thing)
  (if (member thing '(dog cat snail mouse)) t))
```

It is fairly simple to ask:

```
(animalp 'dog)
```

Things get more complicated after splitting into packages:

```
(in-package :common-lisp-user)
(defpackage :animalia
  (:use :common-lisp)
  (:export :animalp))

(in-package :animalia)
(defun animalp (thing)
  (if (member thing '(dog cat snail mouse)) t))
```

Now, one can still ask the same question:

```
(animalia:animalp 'animalia::dog)
```

But it is getting messy.  (I'm not fussed about "animalia:animalp", it's the large number of animals that is problematic.)  Essentially I'd like to be able to ask:

```
(animalia:animalp 'dog)
```

The symbols (dog, cat, etc) don't have any properties - essentially I've been using them as a shorthand for string comparisons:

```
(if (member "dog" '("dog" "cat" "mouse" "snail")
            :test #'string-equal) t)
```

**So my question is around best practice.**  I'm not enamoured with using strings - especially when (eq 'dog 'dog) is so simple within a single package.  On the other hand, neither am I overjoyed with the prospect of (defpackage ... (:export :dog :cat ...)) and needing to qualify each animal with a package (animialia:dog, etc).  The final obvious solution is to make all the animals keywords, like:

```
(if (member :dog '(:dog :cat :mouse :snail)) t)
```

but even that just seems a little dirty.

What are some best practice solutions to achieve what I want, without making a complete mess or resorting to the evolution of fanciful, ugly and potential fragile solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Note that **string-equal** accepts *string designators*, and that symbols are string designators.  You can be very flexible and define **animalp** in terms of **string-equal**.  This does mean that you're doing string comparison, but it doesn't require you use actual strings in other places in your code.

```
(defpackage #:animalia
  (:use "COMMON-LISP"))

(in-package #:animalia)

(defun animalp (x)
  (if (member x '(cat dog fish)
              :test 'string-equal)
      t))

(in-package #:cl-user)

(animalia::animalp :fish)            ;=> T  (keyword)
(animalia::animalp 'cl-user::fish)   ;=> T  (non-animalia package)
(animalia::animalp 'animalia::fish)  ;=> T  (animalia package)
(animalia::animalp '#:fish)          ;=> T  (no package)

(animalia::animalp "fish")           ;=> T  (strings, any      
(animalia::animalp "FISH")           ;=> T   case is OK)
```

If you want quick symbol equality for making **animalp** faster, you'll have to either

1. use keywords, which are readily accessible everywhere; or
2. use symbols defined in the animalia package (and probably export and **use** them in packages that should have access).

You can also take the approach in [id256's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29005809/1281433) where you first convert the input to a string, **intern** it, and then check for membership.  However, that must involve the system going through the interning process, which might defeat the purpose, especially for such a small list of animals.  It also has the potentially undesirable effect of cluttering up your **animalia** package. If you're willing to do something like **interning**, though, it might make more sense to just use a hash table to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

The solution with keywords is pretty standard and works fine, but if you want to avoid using it and pass symbol from any package to `animalp`, you can intern it in the `animalia` package:

```
(in-package :animalia)
(defun animalp (thing)
   (and (member (intern (string thing) :animalia)
                '(dog cat snail mouse))
        t))
```

Note that the second parameter of `intern` (PACKAGE to intern the symbol in) is optional and by default its value is the `*current-package*`, which is `:cl-user` in the moment of call. To deal with this you can explicitly use `:animalia`.

Comment: This certainly works, but it has the unfortunate side effect of cluttering up the symbols in the animalia package, and it's not clear whether the benefits of quick symbol comparison are worth the tradeoff of interning on every call.  (Of course, in considerations like that, we also would have the issues of why the animals are in a list rather than an array, etc.)

Comment: I don't think the potential heap exhausion resulting from interning a lot of symbols is a real-life problem, unless there are millions of symbol, which is rather rare.

Comment: No, the size probably isn't an issue, but anything that does [do-symbols](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_do_sym.htm) might be surprised by the lots of "extra" symbols in the animalia package.

Comment: Oh yes, but I think do-symbols is as rare as millions of symbols, unless one is implementing lisp from scratch.